# How to calculate velocity of a column in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file  which has two columns, the first is a Id of a person and the second the velocity. I want to find the average speed for every ID.

My csv file looks like this:

```
0001;12
0001;0.14
0001;96
0002;19
0002;20
0002;6.3
0003;25
0003;1.9
0003;16
```

I am a beginner in Python and don't really know many Python tricks. What I do know is that I probably complicated my code too much.

Comment: Maybe start here: [13.1. csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Where's the complicated code? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use Python 3.5

Comment: Fatima: Off-topic - When you respond to a comment from someone, if you put @their_user_name in the text of your response, they will automatically receive a notification of that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to read the data from the file:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

filename = 'velocities.csv'

# read user velocities from file into a dictionary of lists
user_velocities = {}
with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    for user_id, velocity in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'):
        user_velocities.setdefault(user_id, []).append(float(velocity))

print('User velocities read from file:', filename)
pprint(user_velocities)
```

Output:

```
User velocities read from file: velocities.csv
{'0001': [12.0, 0.14, 96.0],
 '0002': [19.0, 20.0, 6.3],
 '0003': [25.0, 1.9, 16.0]}
```

It should now be easy for you to figure out how compute the average velocity for each user id in the `user_velocities` dictionary from the list of values associated with each one.

<sup>(Hint: use the built-in `sum()` and `len()` functions.)</sup>